# How to add #temp tables

Tags: database, t-sql

I have formed few temp tables in my query (TSQL) like - #temphold1, #temphold2, #temphold3..... #temphold10. Each temp table has different schema (different columns) each derived by grouping data from different tables with specific conditions. I need to determine a way to carry all these temp tables to the User Interface and display each table seperately. Is there a way I can add all temp tables with specific indexer that i can retrieve at the User Interface.

thanks for any reply.

Comment: What is the user interface?  Something you have created, or are you referring to Management Studio?

Comment: To run the query as a stored procedure and output to the User Interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such indexer.

However, SQL Server and ADO.NET support returning multiple result sets by selecting each table in turn.

See this [howto](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311274) on MSDN (How To Handle Multiple Results by Using the DataReader in Visual C# .NET).

So, in your stored procedure:

```
-- after populating your temp tables:
SELECT * FROM #table1
SELECT * FROM #table2
SELECT * FROM #table3
```

In essence, after reading the first recordset, you call `NextResult()` on the DataReader in order to get the results of the next select:

```
while(dr.Read())
{
   // process data from #table1
}

dr.NextResult();

while(dr.Read())
{
   // process data from #table2
}

dr.NextResult();

while(dr.Read())
{
   // process data from #table3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning results to C#, you can do it with a DataAdapter like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string")) {
    SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[] {
        new SqlParameter("@param1",10),
        new SqlParameter("@param2","test")
    };
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter("spStoredProcName", conn);
    sa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sa.Fill(ds);
    //ds.Tables[0] == first table
    //ds.Tables[1] == second table
    //... etc.
    //Do whatever you need to here
}
```